# Junit for GetMethod/ mocking response body

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, junit, mocking

Hello I am facing issues while writing junit for one of the methods in my code. I tried some solutions but nothing helped. I will try to list down all the things I tried.

My method is something like this :

```
val getResponse = GetMethod(location)
 val responseCode = capsClient.executeMethod(getResponse)
 if (responseCode != Response.Status.OK.statusCode) {// throwing exception}

file.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
getCalsResponse.responseBodyAsStream.use { inputStream ->
inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)}
```

the responseBodyAsStream is coming as null and that is breaking my test case. I checked it's inside HttpBaseMethod and I tried mocking that as well but it didn't work.

My test case :

```
`val getMethod: HttpMethod = mock()
 when(getMethod.getName()).thenReturn("GET")
 whenever(getMethod.responseBody).thenReturn("asdasdasdasdadasdasd".toByteArray())`
```

I tried mocking methodBase as well to return mocked resposneBody

`val methodBase : HttpMethodBase = mock() whenever(methodBase.responseBody).thenReturn("hello response body".toByteArray())`